# API Domain Error on iOS 8 not on iOS 10 version? (AFNetworking)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3, app-transport-security

We are facing domain error only on iOS 8 versions and not able to get response from API but the same code works fine on iOS 10 versions. I have attached the required information below, please check and let me know if any solution.

**AFNetworking Version** : 3.1.0

**ERROR:**

```
" Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo=0x7fd440dc6e00 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fd44586cbb0> { URL: http://......../users/login } { status code: 401, headers {
"Accept-Ranges" = none;
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 381;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
Date = "Fri, 27 Oct 2017 10:17:40 GMT";
"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
"Proxy-Support" = "Session-Based-Authentication";
Server = Apache;
Via = "HTTP/1.1 sophos.http.proxy:3128";
"Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm="Restricted"";
} }"
```

**CODE:**

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]; 
[manager POST:url parameters:parameters 
constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> _Nonnull formData)
 { 
} progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) { } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id _Nullable    responseObject) 
{     
NSLog(@"responseObject %@",responseObject); 
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error)
 { 
NSLog(@"err : %ld",(long)[error code]); NSLog(@"err : %@",[error description]);
 }];
```

**API:** HTTP (Development)

we have added ATS key,

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> <dict> <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> <true/> </dict>
```

in plist.

Please let me know if any solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code instead of your code**

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:strUrl parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
    NSError * error=nil;

    NSLog(@"Decoded: %@", responseObject);
    NSMutableDictionary * parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];

completionHandler:Callback(parsedData,nil);

    NSLog(@"Decoded: %@", parsedData);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
completionHandler:Callback(nil,error);

}];
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code not working in iOS 8.2 but working fine in iOS 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

**i hope this code works for ios 8 or 10**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];

[manager POST:stUrl parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        if(success) {
            success(responseObject);
        }
    }
    else {
        NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
        if(success) {
            success(response);
        }
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    if(failure) {
        failure(error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Sorry, We are using AFNetwork version 3.1.0. There is no AFHTTPRequestOperationManager any more. We should use AFHTTPSessionManager instead.